# Internal testing links show Something went wrong in google play store

Tags: android, flutter

I've uploaded the aab file and have entered the emails to access the testing apk, but for some cellphones it displays "something went wrong" in the playstore, I've cleared the playstore cache but still can't. Is there anyone here who can help me?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i1sXx.jpg)

Answer (score 3):

Had the same issue today and figured out how to fix it.

1. In '**internal testing**' page, click '**view release details**', in 'App bundles' section, click the **arrow button** (Details).
2. In the App bundle dialog, click '**Downloads**'. Then click '**Manage access**'. It will redirect to 'Internal app sharing' page.
3. set up the '**Uploaders and tester**' and '**Email lists**', then click 'Save changes'

Answer (score 2):

You also need invite them to join in Tester's list.

On Google Console:

- Click in `Internal Testing` inside `Testing` menu.
- Click in `Testers` section, right of `Releases`
- Then in `Join on the web` **copy the link** and share with your testers.

[image: Google Play Console]

Comment: This is the answer! Why is this so buried...

Comment: I have done this, but still get the same error message. Perhaps I just need to wait for some time??

Comment: @bobmoff, you also need to become a developer on the target device's Google Play. Click Google Play version in the app's settings 7 times, then you can find Developer Options in settings and allow "Internal App Sharing". Oh, the crazy incantations you need to just get an app installed.

Comment: @bobmoff did you end up getting access after waiting longer? Or did you have to do something else to get access?

Comment: @AdamJohns sorry, i dont even remember. I think it worked after some time, or maybe i did upload a new release. Not sure.

Answer (score 1):

battling the same issue here but it make sure (if you have multiple versions available for testing) that you're generating a new link from:
**Internal testing** > **Click the '->' on your App bundle** > **Click the 'Downloads' tab** > **then Copy the shareable link and share that**
Also double check that your user group is set up with that distribution and that the appropriate emails are spelled correctly. I hope this helps.

Comment: Hello, everyone. I am facing same issue since many days. Even I have updated email properly. I have also tried installing app from download link from App Release Detail page, still that link is not working. I don't understand why **Something Went Wrong** error is coming, even my app status for internal version is also showing as **active** on dashboard. Help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This issue can occur when you have multiple Google accounts on a phone.

- Make sure you only have one of your personal email addresses in your internal testing group
- When you follow the link, ensure you are logged in to the correct account using the button in the top right corner of the webpage.

Afterward, the download link should work successfully.

Comment: This worked for me.  Thanks for posting.

Answer (score 0):

Kindly note if your app is already published once, then decided to be available to your Closed or Internal testing track testers, its status must be "Published" again. Otherwise, it won't show up in the Play Store.

Comment: Internal Testing does not require Play Store publishing. I have not yet published my app on Play Store but the internal testers can see it when it's accessed through the Internal Testers Join link

Comment: in my case, app is already published and decided to make it available for internal testers only.